# Materials in the game engine have no shadows

Tags: game-engine, shaders

I am trying to make a game in blender, but any material that I add to anything in the game has no shadows
[image]

Comment: Switch to material mode before starting the game

Comment: i tried that but only the land had shading, the house stayed all white even in material mode, i appended this house into this scene, could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Maybe. Did you assign a material to it?

Comment: i did, but it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic shadows. Check the shdow propery of your lamp object.

[image]

Or bake your shadows in blender render or cycles, what can lead to better performance, however they will be static.

Comment: thanks for your help, but i found out that if i just appended the meshes in material mode i wouldnt have the problem

Comment: **@K1320** what do you mean by "appended the meshes in material mode..."? Turning on shadows in Game mode is exactly as atevm described. Unless you are not interested in the models casting shadows but rather show shading on the surface of your model?